# find all meromorphic functions such that

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all functions f which are meromorphic in a neighborhood of $\left\{|z|\le 1 \right\}$ and such that $|f(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$ , f has a double pole at $z=\frac{1}{2}$, a triple zero at $z=-\frac{1}{3}$ and no other zeros or poles in $\left\{|z|<1 \right\}$

I have no idea how can I do this problem :S! Maybe using laurent expansion and uniqueness of that , but I don't know how can I find the general form of such functions, please help me :/ I want to see an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use idea of [Blaschke product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) to construct desired function.

Function $f_0(z)=\left(\dfrac{z+\dfrac{1}{3}}{1+\dfrac{1}{3}z}\right)^3$ has zero of multiplicity $3$ at point $z_2=-\dfrac{1}{3}$. Analogously, function $f_p(z)=\left(\dfrac{z-\dfrac{1}{2}}{1-\dfrac{1}{2}z}\right)^2$ has zero of multiplicity $2$ at point $z_p=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Their quotient $g(z)=\dfrac{f_0(z)}{f_p(z)}$ will be meromorphic in the unit circle with predescribed poles and zeroes.  At last, arbitrary rotations $f(z)=e^{i\varphi}g(z)$ will  possess the same properties.

Comment: well i'm very stupid... I don't know how to use such Blaschke products , I don't know nothing about that

Comment: Oh I found something about Blaschke products, it's a characterization that will be helpful , thanks for the answer